# My css class is not loading while running the project

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, frontend, web-frontend

CSS class is not loading while running the project, because of that class, CSS is not applied and all the CSS is written in one file. I can't see the CSS and that particular class in HTML while checking through inspect element.

Please help me to fix the issue.
Regards,
Neeti

Comment: Context please, no file structure, etc?

Comment: check network if your css file is loaded with/without error

Comment: it's loaded without error. @flip kovac